# How do you show people the status of a website if you're building it locally?

Tags: web, wamp, local

I'm making a website for my brother (first time). I installed WAMP and I'm building it locally on my computer with Wordpress and everything. So there's a database involved. How do I go about showing him what it currently looks like without him being next to me?

Comment: Screenshots or screen share? https://join.me/

Answer (score 0):

If he is on the same local network as you, then you can simply tell him your IP address and he can visit it in his browser.

For example, if your IP address is 192.168.1.111 then he can visit:

```
http://192.168.1.111
```

in his browser. Of course, depending on how you've setup WAMP, he might see your WAMP install and then need to click on the correct directory to see your Wordpress installation.

Here's a random website that instructs you on how to [view your IP address in Windows](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aapa.html)

If he is not on the same network as you, you could setup your IP address to be a DMZ (or only port forward port 80) in your router. Then anyone on the internet can go to the IP address of your home router and see the site.

Comment: Going to my IP address brings me to my ASUS router configuration page. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: You went to your ASUS router's IP address if you saw your ASUS router's configuration page. Did you follow the instructions here: http://kb.iu.edu/data/aapa.html to find your IP address?

Comment: Your IP shows if you type "my IP" in google. I put my IP in the browser and a popup shows up. The popup says "a user name and password are being requested by (my ip address) The site says 'RT-AC66R'" which is the name of my router. The only log in user name and password which then allows me to move forward is the user name and pw to my Internet which then brings me to my router configuration page

Comment: Sigh. Don't go to Google, it will show the IP of your router. Just follow the directions I provided.